# How can I install Lantern on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, linux, software-installation, debian

#### Purpose

I bought a Raspberry Pi 2 B , and I want to build a [Lantern](https://github.com/getlantern/lantern) network at home. So I want to use the Raspberry Pi as a router.

#### What I know

1. I know the Lantern for Linux version is based on Debian, and Raspbian is also based on Debian.
2. I found a version of Lantern for [Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit](https://github.com/getlantern/lantern), but I don't know if it will work on Raspbian.

How could I use the Pi as a router for Lantern?

Answer (score 3):

The pre-built Ubuntu packages will not work, so you will probably have to build it from source. That means setting up a developer stack on your Pi, installing `go` and `docker` and `make`.

From there, you will need to get [`gost`](https://github.com/getlantern/gost), that in turn, from what I can read, will download the Lantern sources.

Then you should be able to use this [guide](https://github.com/getlantern/lantern/blob/master/README.md#setting-up-a-development-environment) to build and run lantern.

Note that I haven't tried. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've built a headless `lantern` binary package for raspbian.
You can download and install it manually.

```
wget https://github.com/EasyPi/docker-lantern-arm/releases/download/2.2.5/lantern_2.2.5-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i lantern_2.2.5-1_armhf.deb
sudo systemctl start lantern
sudo systemctl enable lantern
curl -x https://127.0.0.1:8787 https://www.google.com/
```

If you want to build it by yourself, please read [this](https://github.com/vimagick/rpi-bin/wiki/lantern).